# how to take id in loop and modal to edit and update data using codeigniter 3 and jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, codeigniter-3

I made product data display using loop with ci3 framework. when you want to edit the data using the modal, the data in the modal form has successfully appeared, but when it is updated, only the data in the first row can change its data, while the data in the second and subsequent rows cannot be changed. I use the ci3 framework and jquery ajax to edit and update data.

how do you make the second data and so on can be updated using the jquery modal and ajax in a loop.
please help

here is the form code

```
<td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-info" data-toggle="modal" title="edit" data-target="#edit<?= $t['id_produk'] ?>"><i class="la la-pencil"></i></button>

                        <!-- Modal edit produk-->
                        <div class="modal fade text-left" id="edit<?= $t['id_produk'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel17" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <form id="form_edit_pro">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel17">Edit Produk</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <input type="text" value="<?= $t['id_produk'] ?>" name="id<?= $t['id_produk'] ?>" id="editID<?= $t['id_produk'] ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn grey btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Update</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

following is jquery ajax code to send to controller

```
 <script>
        $('#form_edit_pro').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevensikan submit form secara default

            // Kirim data ke server menggunakan metode POST dan Ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url('admin/admin/update_produk2') ?>',
                data: $("#form_edit_pro").serialize(), // Ambil data dari form yang memanggil metode ini
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Tampilkan pesan sukses atau error dari server
                    if (response.success) {
                        // Jika berhasil menyimpan, tampilkan pesan sukses
                        alert('Berhasil diupdate');
                    } else {
                        // Jika gagal menyimpan, tampilkan pesan error
                        alert('Gagal diupdate');
                    }
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
        //edit data tutup
    </script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

because form_edit_pro not only 1, you can change action like this

add class `btnUpdate` in your update button

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn grey btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btnUpdate">Update</button>
</div>
```

in your script change to click function and find form in your open modal

```
<script>
  $('.btnUpdate').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevensikan submit form secara default

    // Kirim data ke server menggunakan metode POST dan Ajax
    let form = $(this).closest('#form_edit_pro');
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url('admin/admin/update_produk2') ?>',
      data: form.serialize(), // Ambil data dari form yang memanggil metode ini
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        // Tampilkan pesan sukses atau error dari server
        if (response.success) {
          // Jika berhasil menyimpan, tampilkan pesan sukses
          alert('Berhasil diupdate');
        } else {
          // Jika gagal menyimpan, tampilkan pesan error
          alert('Gagal diupdate');
        }
        location.reload();
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("error");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.
your answer can only retrieve the value from the first row, while the next row cannot be retrieved. how's that?

Comment: i try in my php this working, maybe you can look in Inspect->Network, in your request check Payload

Comment: and change your input, change name only id, dont use <?= $t['id_produk'] ?> like this <input type="text" value="<?= $t['id_produk'] ?>" name="id" id="editID<?= $t['id_produk'] ?>">

Comment: I have tried but still can't. I looked at the console.log for the id, it says undefine. what else is missing?

Comment: <input type="text" value="<?= $t['id_produk'] ?>" name="id" id="editID<?= $t['id_produk'] ?>">

Comment: <script>
        $('.btnUpdate').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

           var editID = $("#editID").val();
           console.log(editID);
           
        });
    </script>

Comment: chamge your id from id="editID<?= $t['id_produk'] ?>" to id="editID" , and you cant use var editID = $("#editID").val();,

Comment: use closest like my code, let form = $(this).closest('#form_edit_pro');, and get editID like this, form.find("#editID").val()